# how to unzip multiple zip files

Tags: php, unzip

I have several ziped files in a folder. I would like to unzip them to a specified folder. I have the following php code:

```
$path = "docs/" . $ID;
$files = scandir("temp" . '/' . $ID );
foreach ($files as $athely){
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($athely);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract it to the path we determined above
  $zip->extractTo($path);
  $zip->close();
  echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
} else {
  echo "Doh! I couldn't open $athely";
}
}
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a library that has an unzip object?  Where is `ZipArchive` coming from?

Comment: @Sablefoste ZipArchive is part of the Zip extension. 99% of PHP installations will be compiled with it already http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: In my case it is true

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you are not using full path for opening the zip. Another thing to notice is if more than one zip file have folder with same name then one folder will overwrite the other.

```
<?php
    $path = "docs/" . $ID;
    $files = scandir("temp" . '/' . $ID );

    foreach ($files as $athely){
    if($athely=="." || $athely=="..") continue;

    $target_path = "temp/".$ID."/".$athely;
    $file = $athely;

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($target_path);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
      $zip->extractTo($path);
      $zip->close();
      echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
     } else {
      echo "Doh! I couldn't open $athely";
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Everything is okay, the only problem is that the first file is always extracted to the the root. What am I doing wrong? I get something like this:(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxa14mvvrcThb0dWYWpESEpYVDQ/view?usp=sharing).(I had a file named '1.zip' too in the folder)

Comment: @user2666249  It will be based on the nature of zip file.. zip file may have a folder inside or files without a folder. If its files without a folder it will be on the root. If its files with in a folder then it will be like your case 2.zip , 3.zip so the better option is create a folder each time with some temporary name. you just open each zip file in your temp directory you will understand the first zip file have no folder inside.

Comment: I think there is some other problem. All the files have the same structure (they are copies). I can add you to my project on gitlab if you need it.